# Set Top Margin Only in android?

Tags: android, layout, margins

I am trying to set the top margin only pragmatically, i am doing this

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
 params.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
 tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

now the issue is i've given some value of right margin left margin values in xml file, and by doing this through coding in java class it disturbs the xml values, is there any way to set the top margin only?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify `topMargin` of `params` directly:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the answer looks something like this:

```
     TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
     params.topMargin = 10;
     tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: That 10 is it 10 pixels or 10 DPI?

Comment: Everything in the documentation for this class is in pixels:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html  There's a number of examples if you need to convert between dpi and pixels.

Answer (score 3):

Get the other margins and set them again:

```
int leftMargin = params.leftMargin;
int rightMargin = params.rightMargin;
int bottomMargin = params.bottomMargin;

params.setMargins(leftMargin, rightMargin, 10, bottomMargin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```